# Is there a word that's used to qualify a different world that has a shared space with ours?

Tags: word-request

> The spirit world is * to our physical world.

When we use parallel world, it usually means that the world doesn't share the same worldspace and that exist independently to ours, but what about the spirit world. The spirit world, typically speaking, exist within our world and share the same space. How do you qualify such world? Is there a word for it?

Comment: "The spirit world" does not have an obvious meaning in English, so we're going to have trouble finding this word.  Can you describe in other words the concept you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One word might be "superimposed" - "superimposed (adj.) with one layer on top of another." Or, "coincides" - "correspond in position; meet or intersect."

E.g.

> The spirit world is superimposed on our physical world.

Or

> The spirit world coincides with our physical world.

I'm not sure exactly, but there are a few other phrases you could use..

> The spirit world exists on the same plane of reality as our own.

Comment: I guess this answer includes many good, appropriate expressions for it. As **superimposed** makes sense here, then how about **superposed**?